# Migrating GIT repository keeping history intact

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-branch

I am trying to migrate an existing repository from Gitlab to Github. Size of the repository is 8gb. On inspecting found out that the size of pack file created inside the ".git" folder is almost 7.5gb. If I delete the `.git` folder, do `git init`, and then push the repository to Github, all the commit history and branch information is gone.Other than the master branch, there are DEV and IT branches. This is what I am looking to do:

1. Archive the master branch with all its commit history.
2. Create a new branch, without any history, which will now act as the master branch.
3. Delete history for DEV and IT branches.
   Is this possible? I just want to keep commit history for the master branch, as it will reduce the pack file's size by 6 gb.

Comment: You can't "keep history and also delete it". For git to know the history, it must have a record of what happened. Are you saving large binary files in your repository? In that case git stores a complete copy of each version of your file. Does running `git gc` reduce the size?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could completely destroy the `dev` and `it` branches from history. It probably won't change the repository size much, and it doesn't address the core problem: your repo is bloated. There are much better ways of reducing repository size.

Unless your other branches diverge wildly from the master branch, like they store *completely* different and large content and were never merged into master, deleting them from history won't make much difference for the repository size. This is because Git history is all built on top of each other.

The history of a Git repository looks something like this:

```
          J - K - L                   T - U [dev]
         /         \                 /
A - B - C - H - I - M - N - O - Q - R - S - V [master]
         \                      /        \
          ---------D - E - F - P          X - Y [it]
```

The branches are literally branches. When branches are merged, the history of the branch remains, even after the branch is deleted. New branches share all the previous history. So `master` relies on every commit preceding it. So do `dev` and `it`. Destroying dev from history would only save you `t` and `u` because `master` needs all the rest of history.

---

Instead, you need to put your repo on a diet.

If your repository is 7.5 gigs its probably full of large files: videos, images, audio, office documents, big compressed files, etc... Git has a hard time with large binary files, including compressed files, because it cannot store the differences. Every time they change it has to store a whole new copy. This can rapidly bloat the repository size.

Fortunately there's a solution, [`git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) provides "Large File Storage". This lets you transparently store the content of large files in the cloud, but still track their changes in Git, and prevents your repository from getting bloated. You can use it for any new large files you want to store, but what about the ones which have already been stored?

The [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) lets you rewrite your repository to do things like delete files from history, [or change them to use git-lfs](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/releases/tag/v1.12.5).

So you want to run BFG with the `--convert-to-git-lfs` option. You'll have to figure out what files in your repo are large and tell the BFG to filter them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

1.Archive the `master` branch with all its commit history.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master --rebase
git checkout -b archived-master
```

2.Create a new branch, without any history, which will now act as the 
   `master` branch.

```
git checkout master
git checkout --orphan latest_master
git commit -m "master with no history"
git branch -D master
git branch -m latest_master master
```

3.Delete history for `DEV` and `IT` branches.

As there is no way to delete the history of commit(s) alone of a branch, you can create intermediary orphan branch from `DEV` and `IT`, delete them and rename intermediary branch to `DEV` and `IT` respectively, as follows:

**For DEV:**

```
git checkout DEV
git pull origin DEV --rebase
git checkout --orphan intermediary_DEV
git commit -m "DEV with no history"
git branch -D DEV
git branch -m intermediary_DEV DEV
```

**For IT:**

```
git checkout DEV
git pull origin DEV --rebase
git checkout --orphan intermediary_IT
git commit -m "IT with no history"
git branch -D IT
git branch -m intermediary_IT IT
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you type `git push origin master` you are pushing the master branch into a remote called `origin`. In this case your origin is gitlab. So, ... you just need to update this remote, or add a new one. Lets try to add new one called `new-origin`. You just need to run the command

```
git remote add new-origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Now you can open .git/config file and see that there are two remotes. One called origin (that points to gitlab) and another called new-origin (that points to github).

Now that you have two remote, instead of push code into `origin` just push code into `new-origin`. That's all!

Do not push other branches that master.